# Proper use of controllers with MVC (CakePHP)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp, controller

Cake's documentation says "Most commonly, controllers are used to manage the logic for a single model."  I'm finding this is **un**common for most of my code, and I don't want to break convention unless it is proper to do so.

For example, my application sends a user to their account dashboard after they log in - this uses data from probably half a dozen tables, not all of which are even related.  Do I create a "dashboard" controller for this (even though there is no dashboard model or table)?  Or do I create a dashboard method in an existing controller?

Thanks, Brian

Comment: I find Kohana's approach of MVC to be way better than Cake's approach, it's hard to keep Cake's Controllers clean when that's the only logical place (by their own approach) to control the final data output. Kohana uses Views as classes by that reason.

Comment: An example of a Kohana's Controller that does 100 things : http://pastebin.com/cHzhvSYx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar situation and how I handle it is keeping the actions that connect a lot of models in the controller that is the most centric. For instance, my user can create voicenotes, comments, has settings, has twitter and facebook information. All this information I can get from my user model `$this->User->Voicenotes->find('all')`, for example.

I believe creating additional controllers might just confuse you, use what cake gives you, you can specify that models are to be used in a controller either by setting the `$uses` variable or using `loadModel` in the controller action, if you have your relations set up you can just do it the way i described before, no need to create additional controllers.

I guess it depends on how you want your own app to work and what comes easier in your situation.